# How to avoid overlapping plot labels in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to label my horizontal (constant y-axis) plot lines in MATLAB. However, some y-lines overlap and therefore their labels also overlap as shown:

[image: 'Min' and 'Max' lines overlap so their labels overlap]

How may I separate these labels? I am simply using the `yline` function in MATLAB for the horizontal lines.

```matlab
ymax = 0;
ymin = 0;
yline([ymax,ymin],'-',{'Max','Min'})
set(gca,'ylim',[-10,100])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to set the [`LabelVerticalAlignment`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yline.html#mw_eca422bb-7cba-45c7-88b7-35fb0c79c131) property for one of the two lines to `'bottom'`, as follows:

```matlab
ymax = 0;
ymin = 0;
yline(ymax,'-','Max')
yline(ymin,'-','Min','LabelVerticalAlignment','bottom')
set(gca,'ylim',[-10,100])
```

[image]

This property can be set to `'top'` (default), `'middle'` or `'bottom'`.

There is also a [`LabelHorizontalAlignment`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yline.html#mw_791269b1-159a-4bc0-a8b6-c24964ab4be0), which can be set to `'right'` (default), `'left'` or `'center'`.